# Can I debug a webpage on an MFC WebBrowser Control

Tags: c++, mfc, webbrowser-control

I have a desktop application built in `C++` that at one point opens a website in an **MFC WebBrowser Control**. I built this website myself and it looks perfect on standalone `IE11` but when it loads on the **WebBrowser Control** there are some issues with a font not loading. This font provides some icons for the site.

I'm using the **META** tag to force `IE` to render in `IE11` and that's working fine. I just don't know why this font isn't loading on the **WebBrowser Control**.

How can I debug this? The dev tools don't work here so I don't see a way to confirm the font is loading in the first place. Can the **WebBrowser Control** be configured to allow `DevTools`? I read the documentation but I didn't find any mentions of that.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What browser version are you using, check [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version)

Comment: @xMRi I'm using IE11 and adding the X-UA-Compatible META tag just in case, to avoid older modes. I'll check out the article. Thank you.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what this has to do with VB.NET, when you mentioned C++?

Comment: @VisualVincent I don't actually work on the desktop app, so I thought since the app is in Windows and the team is 100% Windows based, I figured they built it in the vb.net environment. Also, it was one of the tags recommended so I went with it. I'll remove if it's not accurate.

Comment: Well, it's not ;). VB.NET and C++ aren't even remotely close to each other. They're two completely different languages, and the only thing they have in common is that the .NET Framework (the VB.NET/C#/etc. environment) was built with C++.

Comment: Have a look at [FireBug Lite](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Mar/08/Debugging-the-Web-Browser-Control-with-FireBug).

Comment: @zett42 Thank you! I've been looking for that like crazy Googling by I could not remember the name! I've FireBug Lite a long time ago but the name had abandoned me completely. We'll see what I find. Thanks!